# .NET WinForms Localization - How to make control position based on length of text

Tags: winforms, localization, positioning, anchor

I am working on localizing a WinForms application through satellite assemblies. The problem I am facing is that when I switch to some other language such as Japanese from English, the labels overlap (or go behind) the combo boxes because of the change in text. The change in text causes Label width to increase making them jump over to other controls.

Is there a way (maybe through Anchoring) to overcome this so that the combo boxes decrease their width automatically to compensate for the Label size increase? Something like anchoring WRT a control instead of a Form.

**UPDATE**
OK. I think I've found a solution to this one. The Form has a **Language** property which is used to set language specific properties for a Form. If I change it to Japanese and make changes to Form layout and Control positions then these language specific items are stored in a new .RESX file for each Form. The Satellite assemblies will still be used to provide the localized strings but these RESX files will resize the Form elements accordingly. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form has a Language property which is used to set language specific properties for a Form. If I change it to Japanese and make changes to Form layout and Control positions then these language specific items are stored in a new .RESX file for each Form. The Satellite assemblies will still be used to provide the localized strings but these RESX files will resize the Form elements accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything that can resolve satisfactorily your problem.
There is the property **AutoEllipsis=True** (with **AutoSize=False**) that can alleviate the situation.

If set to True this property insert three dot to the right of the label when the text exceed the label dimensions. Positioning the mouse over the label will dispaly a tooltip with the full text.